# Unsure what I'm doing wrong with CORS, woocommerce API with a separate React website

Tags: reactjs, woocommerce, cors, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a locally hosted wordpress installation using woocommerce, and a separate locally hosted react webapp that will be used to manage the products. I'm using the woocommerce-rest-api react plugin to call the end points.
GETs work fine and don't have any issues, however PUT and DELETE I'm having issues with CORS.

I've updated the wordpress htaccess:
[image]

and call the endpoint like so:

[image]

and this is what I get in dev tools:

[image]

Here is the preflight headers and response and then the failing call:
[image]

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your preflight response from (what i assume is the wordpress server) appears to be missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response (sent back from the OPTIONS request).

To match your other requests this should be *.  However it is not best practice to use * for security reasons and should instead use the domains you want to be able to access this from browsers.

Comment: Okay so it’s the Wordpress server side that I need to fix. How do I make it so that the header is returned correctly?

Comment: ive just noticed i think your header lines inside htaccess, are in the wrong block.  the lines begining with "Header set" need to be inside the <IfModuled mod_headers.c> block

Comment: I've tried adding those into mod_headers block and still seeing the same issue, I'm still not seeing the correct pre-flight response